# Does Jest Support stealjs

Tags: jestjs, ca, babel-jest, stealjs

Hello was trying to run canjs v2.3 for JEST but it seems it returns an error after testing: Reference: steal is not defined.

I am not sure if bundling with stealjs is supported with Jest, I can't also find resources online regarding this ticket. I am not really sure if I understood this correctly if not please give light to my concern.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that it is. I think Jest pretty much expects that you use Jest. I'll ask around.

Comment: What do you mean about Jest expects jest? I used steal for compilation yet it did not worked